# Is there a way to identify the "replied to" message with Messenger API

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

1. My Messenger bot asks a question:

> "What is your favorite color ?"

2. My webhook receives a reply message:

> "Red"

How can the webhook identify what was the question ?
Do I need to store something like the "lastQuestionSent" in the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep track of it in a session for that user. Maintaining sessions will pay dividends down the line.

You could include a reference to the question in your callback payload.